# Permutaciones en C++

Tags: c++

Buenas he estado estudiando acerca de lo que son permutaciones a tal punto que me he propuesto como reto el poder programarlos en c++, Tal es mi asombro que es un problema muy difícil para mi capacidad actual, así que encontré un código que permite hacer permutaciones simples a chars, Adjunto código:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int formas = 0;
void Cambiar(char *x, char *y)
{
   char pivote;
   pivote = *x;
   *x = *y;
   *y = pivote;
}

void permutar(char *Ar, int izq, int der)
{

int i;

if (izq == der)
{
    //* Si en caso todas las formas posibles ya
    //*esten en el arreglo Ar, entonces lo imprimimos
    if (formas < 10)
    {
        cout << "0" << formas << ".\t" << Ar << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << formas << ".\t" << Ar << endl;
    }

    formas++; //! Vamos aumentando el numero de permutaciones
}
else
{
    for (i = izq; i <= der; i++)
    {
        Cambiar((Ar + izq), (Ar + i));
        permutar(Ar, izq + 1, der);
        Cambiar((Ar + izq), (Ar + i));
    }
}
}

int main()
{
int n = 0;
char cadena[] = "AEBCD";

cout << "\n\n\t[ PERMUTACIONES - MESA - ABOGADOS ] \n\n";

n = strlen(cadena);

permutar(cadena, 0, n - 1);
cout << "\nSe realizo " << formas << " permutaciones.en total\n"<< endl;
return 0;
}
```

Lo que entiendo es el main, se da una cadena, se mide su longitud, y la manda a la función permutar, manda la cadena, la pos 0 y la ultima pos,
lo que no entiendo mucho es la función permutar, entiendo que si el lado izquierdo y derecho no sean iguales, aplicara recursividad, pero mas que todo no entiendo el porque nuevamente pone cambiar abajo de permutar. ¿No se supone que cuando llama a permutar ya no accede a lo que esta abajo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No entiendo el porque nuevamente pone cambiar abajo de permutar. ¿No se supone que cuando llama a permutar ya no accede a lo que esta abajo?

No.

---

Cuando se llama a una función, ésta se ejecuta hasta el final y después se retoma la ejecución en el punto de llamada a la misma. Esto sucede incluso cuando la función se llama a si misma, cada llamada se ejecutará hasta el final y después se retomará la ejecución en el punto de llamada.

Comment: ohhh muchas gracias por darse el tiempo de contestar amigo, tengo otra consulta.. al momento de llamar a la funcion cambiar dentro de la funcion permutar.., esta deberia recibir dos cadenas como argumento, pero en el ejercicio ademas de enviar la cadena, tambien le pone el + izq el cual no logro comprender el porque, segun tengo entendido no se puede sumar una cadena con un numero

Comment: @AlexSantiago efectivamente no se puede sumar una cadena con un número, pero la operación que describes no se compone de una cadena y un número. Te animo a que hagas una nueva pregunta sobre esa duda.

Comment: Dale amigo la formulo ahora Mismo, muchas gracias